# I am looking to convert rows into columns of the output and need to perform the mathematical operation on top of it

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's my input table:Account

```
accountnumber year   quarter    catgeory    owedamt  payedamt 
101           2001     1        Tax         100.0      0.0
101           2001     1        Interest    100.0      30.0
101           2001     2        Interest    100.0       20.0
102           2002     1        Tax         100.0      100.0
```

output

```
accountnumber  year   quarter    Tax (outstanding)       Interest (outstanding)
101            2001     1           100.0                      70.0
101            2001     2            0.0                       80.0
102            2002     1            0.0                       0.0
```

Here "outstanding" is caluclated on the basis of owedamt - payedamt

Note: we need to have the columns as Tax and Interest but the amount in those columns should be outstanding which is calculated on the basis os above formula.

Note 2: for the accountntumber:102 ,Tax (outstanding) is calculated
owedamt - payedamt which is 100.0-100.0=0.0

But we dont have any Interest category in that year and the quarter so the output resulted 0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance your question looks like a rolling average problem of some sort, but it is really just a pivot query in disguise.  We can aggregate by the account number, year, and quarter, and compute the outstanding tax and interest for each period using the amount owed and the amount paid.

```
SELECT
    accountnumber,
    year,
    quarter,
    MAX(CASE WHEN catgeory = 'Tax'
        THEN owedamt - payedamt ELSE 0 END) AS [Tax (outstanding)],
    MAX(CASE WHEN catgeory = 'Interest'
             THEN owedamt - payedamt ELSE 0 END) AS [Interest (outstanding)]
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    accountnumber,
    year,
    quarter
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  accountnumber ,
        year ,
        quarter ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN catgeory = 'Tax' THEN owedamt - payedamt
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS Tax ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN catgeory = 'Interest' THEN owedamt - payedamt
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS Interest
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY accountnumber ,
        year ,
        quarter;
```

EDIT: Not sure if you meant this:

```
with summaryData (accountnumber ,
            year ,
            quarter, tax, interest) as 
(
    SELECT  accountnumber ,
            year ,
            quarter ,
            SUM(CASE WHEN catgeory = 'Tax' THEN owedamt - payedamt
                     ELSE 0
                END),
            SUM(CASE WHEN catgeory = 'Interest' THEN owedamt - payedamt
                     ELSE 0
                END)
    FROM    mytable
    GROUP BY accountnumber ,
            year ,
            quarter
)
select * from summaryData
where tax > 0 or interest > 0;
```

Comment: How to skip the entire row if all the outstanding s in that  year quarter are zero   e.g 102            2002     1            0.0                       0.0 .... i need to skip these types and i need to keep only atleast any one of the category has value other zero e.g 101            2001     2            0.0                       80.0

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you mean (You already marked the other reply as answer) - probably what you need is a simple where with a CTE.

Comment: PS: I didn't understand why you were after max() value.

Comment: The query is correct but there are many records with zero out standings in tax and interest i need to skip them , i need only the records where the outstanding is not zero in any one of the tax and interest categories

Comment: I already edited my post, but as I said I really didn't understand why you want MAX(). If it is not what you want make your question clear.

Comment: sum() is working perfectly well i will try the edited query